# What is AWSRequestMetricsFullSupport and how do I turn it off?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to save some data from a Spark dataframe to an S3 bucket. This is very simple:

```
dataframe.saveAsParquetFile("s3://kirk/my_file.parquet")
```

The data is successfully saved but but the UI is busy for a very long time. I get thousands of lines of this:

```
2015-09-04 20:48:19,591 INFO  [main] amazonaws.latency (AWSRequestMetricsFullSupport.java:log(203)) - StatusCode=[200], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSRequestID=[5C3211750F4FF5AB], ServiceEndpoint=[https://kirk.s3.amazonaws.com], HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[63.827], HttpRequestTime=[62.919], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[61.678], RequestSigningTime=[0.05], ResponseProcessingTime=[0.812], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.038],
2015-09-04 20:48:19,610 INFO  [main] amazonaws.latency (AWSRequestMetricsFullSupport.java:log(203)) - StatusCode=[204], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSRequestID=[709DA41540539FE0], ServiceEndpoint=[https://kirk.s3.amazonaws.com], HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[18.064], HttpRequestTime=[17.959], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[16.703], RequestSigningTime=[0.06], ResponseProcessingTime=[0.003], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.046],
2015-09-04 20:48:19,664 INFO  [main] amazonaws.latency (AWSRequestMetricsFullSupport.java:log(203)) - StatusCode=[204], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSRequestID=[1B1EB812E7982C7A], ServiceEndpoint=[https://kirk.s3.amazonaws.com], HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[54.36], HttpRequestTime=[54.26], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[53.006], RequestSigningTime=[0.057], ResponseProcessingTime=[0.002], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.034],
2015-09-04 20:48:19,675 INFO  [main] amazonaws.latency (AWSRequestMetricsFullSupport.java:log(203)) - StatusCode=[404], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: AF6F960F3B2BF3AB), S3 Extended Request ID: CLs9xY8HAxbEAKEJC4LS1SgpqDcnHeaGocAbdsmYKwGttS64oVjFXJOe314vmb9q], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404 Not Found], AWSRequestID=[AF6F960F3B2BF3AB], ServiceEndpoint=[https://kirk.s3.amazonaws.com], Exception=1, HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[10.111], HttpRequestTime=[10.009], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[8.758], RequestSigningTime=[0.043], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.044],
2015-09-04 20:48:19,685 INFO  [main] amazonaws.latency (AWSRequestMetricsFullSupport.java:log(203)) - StatusCode=[404], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: F2198ACEB4B2CE72), S3 Extended Request ID: J9oWD8ncn6WgfUhHA1yqrBfzFC+N533oD/DK90eiSvQrpGH4OJUc3riG2R4oS1NU], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404 Not Found], AWSRequestID=[F2198ACEB4B2CE72], ServiceEndpoint=[https://kirk.s3.amazonaws.com], Exception=1, HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[9.879], HttpRequestTime=[9.776], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[8.537], RequestSigningTime=[0.05], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.033],
```

I can understand if some users are interested in logging the latency of S3 operations, but is there any way to disable any and all monitoring and logging from `AWSRequestMetricsFullSupport`?

When I check the Spark UI it tells me that the job completed relatively quickly, but the console is flooded with these messages for a very long time.

Comment: For context, I am saving a dataframe of 1m rows & 500 columns. It takes about 20 seconds to save, but the latency warnings appear in my console for >20 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resp. [AWS SDK for Java source comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/util/AWSRequestMetricsFullSupport.java#L63) reads:

```java
/**
 * Start an event which will be timed. [...]
 * 
 * This feature is enabled if the system property
 * "com.amazonaws.sdk.enableRuntimeProfiling" is set, or if a
 * {@link RequestMetricCollector} is in use either at the request, web service
 * client, or AWS SDK level.
 * 
 * @param eventName
 *            - The name of the event to start
 * 
 * @see AwsSdkMetrics
 */
```

As further outlined in the referenced [AwsSdkMetrics Java Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/metrics/AwsSdkMetrics.html), you might be able to disable it via the system property:

> The default metric collection of the Java AWS SDK is disabled by
>   default. To enable it, simply specify the system property
>   **"com.amazonaws.sdk.enableDefaultMetrics"** when starting up the JVM.
>   When the system property is specified, a default metric collector will
>   be started at the AWS SDK level. The default implementation uploads
>   the request/response metrics captured to Amazon CloudWatch using AWS
>   credentials obtained via the [`DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html).

This can seemingly be overriden by a `RequestMetricCollector` hard wired *at the request, web service client, or AWS SDK level*, which would presumably require resp. configuration adjustments for the clients/frameworks in use (e.g. Spark here):

> Clients who needs to fully customize the metric collection can
>   implement the SPI [`MetricCollector`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/metrics/MetricCollector.html), and then replace the default AWS
>   SDK implementation of the collector via
>   [`setMetricCollector(MetricCollector)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/metrics/AwsSdkMetrics.html#setMetricCollector(com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricCollector)).

Documentation for these features seems a bit sparse so far, here are two related blog posts I'm aware of:

- [Enabling Metrics with the AWS SDK for Java](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx3C0RV4NRRBKTG/Enabling-Metrics-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-Java)
- [Metric Configuration in AWS SDK for Java](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx2D8OVZ48EQP59/Metric-Configuration-in-AWS-SDK-for-Java)

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I found the same document re: `AwsSdkMetrics`, which (as you posted) indicated that this should be turned off by default. I guess that was an older piece of documentation. Turning this off doesn't seem trivial. I'll follow through the blogs that you referenced eventually.

Answer (score 1):

On release-label EMR silencing these logs proved to be quite a challenge. There was "[an issue with Spark Log4j-based logging in YARN containers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-whatsnew.html)" that was fixed in version emr-4.7.2. A working solution is to add these jsons as configuration:

```
[
{
  "Classification": "hadoop-log4j",
  "Properties": {
    "log4j.logger.com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs": "ERROR",
    "log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.latency": "ERROR"
  },
  "Configurations": []
}
]
```

and in pre emr-4.7.2 also this json that discards the 'buggy' wrong log4j for spark that was the default:

```
[
{
  "Classification": "spark-defaults",
  "Properties": {
    "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'"
  },
  "Configurations": []
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to configure the Java logging (i.e. turn if off) by passing a `log4j` configuration file to the Spark context.

```
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=/home/user/log4j.properties"
```

Where `log4j.properties` is the `log4j` configuration file which disables INFO type messages.